# Как вывести только определенные значения по оси Х?

Tags: r, highcharts

Проблема, что при выводе графика, выводятся другие значения по оси X (как на рисунке)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы по оси Х были только те значения по которым строится график?

```
hc <- highchart() %>%

  hc_add_series( name = 'Значение 1',
                 data = df1,
                 hcaes(x= Date, y = Value),
                 type = 'line') %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy')%>%

  hc_xAxis(tickmarkPlacement = "on",
           type = 'datetime',
           labels = list(format= "{value:%d-%m-%Y}" )) %>%
  hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2,
             xDateFormat = "%d-%m-%Y",
             headerFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
             pointFormat = "Дата: <b>{point.key}</b><br>Толщина: <b>{point.y} [нм]</b>" )%>%
  hc
```

Пример данных data.frame df1:

```
      Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   539.62
2   2017-11-27   540.49  
3   2017-12-01   540.67
4   2017-12-06   540.79
5   2017-12-13   540.71
6   2017-12-20   541.05
7   2017-12-27   540.57
8   2018-01-11   540.78
9   2018-01-18   541.12
10  2018-01-26   541.13
11  2018-01-31   540.83
12  2018-02-16   541.36
13  2018-02-21   540.93
14  2018-03-01   541.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установления произвольных значений в качестве меток на оси, используется параметр `tickPositions`, которые передаётся в `hc_xAxis` или `hc_yAxis`. Особенность `tickPositions` заключается в том, что туда можно передавать только числовые значения. Для того, чтобы данные типа `datetime` отображались корректно, нужно преобразовать даты в формат даты и времени, используемый в JavaScript (количество миллисекунд, прошедшее с 1970-01-01).

```
library(data.table)
library(highcharter)

DT <- fread("
N   Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   539.62
2   2017-11-27   540.49  
3   2017-12-01   540.67
4   2017-12-06   540.79
5   2017-12-13   540.71
6   2017-12-20   541.05
7   2017-12-27   540.57
8   2018-01-11   540.78
9   2018-01-18   541.12
10  2018-01-26   541.13
11  2018-01-31   540.83
12  2018-02-16   541.36
13  2018-02-21   540.93
14  2018-03-01   541.00")

# количество миллисекунд, прошедшее с 1970-01-01
DT[, Date := as.numeric(as.POSIXct(as.Date(Date))) * 1000]

hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series( name = 'Значение 1',
                   data = DT,
                   hcaes(x = Date, y = Value),
                   type = 'line') %>%
    hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
    hc_xAxis(tickmarkPlacement = "on",
             type = 'datetime',
             labels = list(format = "{value:%d-%m-%Y}"),
             tickPositions = DT[, unique(Date)]) %>%
    hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2,
               xDateFormat = "%d-%m-%Y",
               headerFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
               pointFormat = "Дата: <b>{point.key}</b><br>Толщина: <b>{point.y} [нм]</b>" ) %>% 
    hc_plotOptions(global  = list(useUTC = FALSE))

print(hc)
```

[image: Результат выполнения кода]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Только при переводе использовал:
 `df1$Date<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(df1$Date))*1000`
А tickPositions:
`tickPositions = unique(df1$Date)`